# Authentication - proper way of handling session with tokens

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect, refresh-token

I have a ReactJS SPA application which connects to the ASP.NET Core WebAPI. The API is also an authorization server thanks to OpenIddict. I am using *PasswordFlow* and *RefreshTokenFlow* to handle authentication, which means that the server returns an `AccessToken` and optionally a `RefreshToken`. At this moment I struggle with handling *Remember me* functionality properly. When a user wants to rememebered it is no big deal - the server returns an `AccessToken` and a `RefreshToken` which the client stores is `LocalStorage`, so it can refresh the `AccessToken` when it's about to expire or is expired by using `RefreshToken` and it is fine - there is a lot of articles and other helpful resources on the Web. The problem comes when the user does not want to be remembered. How to handle authentication is this scenario? The two solutions I see are:

- the server only issues an `AccessToken`, which the client stores in `SessionStorage`. If it expires - the client forces the user to re-enter his credentials to get a new `AccessToken`. `AccessTokens` should be short-lived (according to what I've learned so far, it can be from one up to several hours, but the more hours it is valid, the less secure it is in a situation when it gets stolen. If it lasts for an hour and after that time the user still uses the application, it seems a bit odd to force him/her to login again.
- the server returns an `AccessToken` and a `RefreshToken` and the client stores it in `SessionStorage`. During the session, if the `AccessToken` is about to expire, the client can get a new one by using the `RefreshToken`. This is risky as well as the server will never know that the user closed his browser and that his/hers `RefreshToken` should be revoked. Assuming that `RefreshTokens` have a way longer lifetime, this seems really risky.

I will be grateful for any thoughts, suggestions and insights on this topic.
Thank you!

Comment: As a general security rule you should never provide to or store the refresh token at the client. The refresh token is only available for 3-legged OAuth which means the server manages the refresh token and not the client. Remember-me should be done at the server and not at the client.

Comment: Another item. To refresh an Access Token, you need three items. Client ID, Client Secret and Refresh Token. You never expose the Client Secret to the client. The Client ID is considered public information. With the Client ID and Client Secret, I can create OAuth tokens using your account. You would expose a huge security hole in your authentication system. Without the Client Secret you cannot refresh Access Tokens or ID Tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new this stuff is tricky to understand, but most implementations work like this:

- The SPA uses the [Open Id Connect Implicit Flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html) via a 3rd party library
- Users are redirected from the SPA to a 3rd party Authorization Server to login
- The Login Process is completely externalized from your app
- After login the Authorization Server returns a token to your SPA
- The SPA calls the API with an access token

PS: I have a [code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) and some [written guidance](http://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) that you might find useful.

Further posts describe how silent token renewal works for an SPA, and as John points out above, an SPA does not use refresh tokens.